# Adding sqlite Qt5 plugin in Yocto

Tags: qt5, yocto

Following [this](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/meta-freescale/2014-April/008066.html) answer, I'm trying to add the sqlite (sqlite3) Qt5 plugin I forgot to enable during the last Yocto build. Here what I did:

Under my own custom layer (`meta-custom-layer/recipes-core`) I added a file `qtbase_%.bbappend`.
Inside I put:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append = " sql-sqlite"
PACKAGECONFIG[sql-sqlite] = "-sql-sqlite,-no-sql-sqlite,sqlite3"
```

Then I deleted the `tmp` folder and issued `bitbake qtbase`. I didn't removed the `sstate-cache` because I added something rather removed or changed.

After parsing the recipes it successfully rebuilt the `tmp` folder but I cannot find anything related to the requested plugin (it should be `libqsqlite.so`).

I didn't understand the answer provided in the link above?
What is the right method to add this plugin?

### UPDATE

To be usre there's nothing else to tune, here the contents of the image bb file:

```
SUMMARY = "blabla"
LICENSE = "Proprietary"

include recipes-st/images/st-image.inc
inherit core-image distro_features_check
CONFLICT_DISTRO_FEATURES = "x11 wayland"

IMAGE_LINGUAS = "en-us"
IMAGE_FEATURES += "splash package-management ssh-server-dropbear"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_MAXSIZE = ""

IMAGE_QT_MANDATORY_PART = " \
   qtbase                  \
   qtbase-plugins          \
   qtbase-tools            \
   "

IMAGE_QT_OPTIONAL_PART = " \
   qtserialport            \
   "

CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " \
    systemd-networkd-configuration \
    \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-core-base      \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-kernel-base    \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-network-base   \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-python2-base   \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-python3-base   \
    \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-core       \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-kernel     \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-network    \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-python2    \
    packagegroup-framework-tools-python3    \
    \
    packagegroup-core-eclipse-debug         \
    \
    ${IMAGE_QT_MANDATORY_PART}  \
    ${IMAGE_QT_OPTIONAL_PART}   \
    "
```

and here the contents of the `RDEPENDS_${PN}` var in `layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/packagegroups/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bb`:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += " \
    packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    qtbase-dev \
    qtbase-mkspecs \
    qtbase-plugins \
    qtbase-staticdev \
    qtconnectivity-dev \
    qtconnectivity-mkspecs \
    qtmqtt-dev \
    qtmqtt-mkspecs \
    qtserialport-dev \
    qtserialport-mkspecs \
    qtserialbus-dev \
    qtserialbus-mkspecs \
    qtsystems-dev \
    qtsystems-mkspecs \
    qttools-dev \
    qttools-mkspecs \
    qttools-staticdev \
    qtwebsockets-dev \
    qtwebsockets-mkspecs \
    qtwebchannel-dev \
    qtwebchannel-mkspecs \
"
```

Comment: often running _bitbake -e_ can shed light on issues like this.

Comment: You've tried searching for `*sqlite*.so*`?

Comment: @RichardNixon yes, but it finds only `libsqlite3*` files, that are not related to the Qt5 plugin.

Comment: 1. which qt5 branch do you use? 2. show output of `bitbake-layers show-appends | grep qtbase`

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk: `qtbase_git.bb:
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.0.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-02-20/layers/meta-st/meta-st-openstlinux/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_git.bbappend`

Comment: `meta-st-openstlinux/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_git.bbappend` -- is this your bbappend?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk: nope. That is the one provided by the vendor (st). Mine is the one described above (in `meta-custom-layer/recipes-core`

Comment: It contains just 4 rows and: `PACKAGECONFIG_append = " eglfs examples accessibility "`

Comment: Then bitbake does not see your bbappend. Make sure the layer is included in `bblayers.conf` and the path to it is similar, e.g. `./youc-customer-layer/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_git.bbappend`

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk, your last comment is the correct answer. I didn't realize I have to replicate *exactly* the same path. I thought it would be enough `qtbase_%.bbappend`.

Answer (score 1):

The PACKAGECONFIG is already [there](https://code.qt.io/cgit/yocto/meta-qt5.git/tree/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_git.bb?h=5.13#n115):

```
PACKAGECONFIG[sql-sqlite] = "-sql-sqlite -system-sqlite,-no-sql-sqlite,sqlite3"
```

Your problem is most likely due to you redefining in (wrongfully as you can see).

You do you have to define new PACKAGECONFIG. Just enable it with:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append = " sql-sqlite"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed. I'm updating the question with some other details.